# How to make a negation in a regular expression in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I have a line:
`abbbbbbbbbbbbbc`.
How can a regular expression take into account that the characters at both ends of this string must be different from each other?
One of the solutions was this:

```
import re

def formating(st):
    if st[0] == st[-1]:
        return 0
    else:
        return len(st)


mask = r"[^a](a{2,}[^a]|[^b]b{2,}[^b]|[^c]c{2,}[^c]|[^d]d{2,}[^d]|[^e]e{2,}[^e]|[^f]f{2,}[^f]|[^g]g{2,}[^g])"

with open("24.txt", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()

result_list = re.findall(mask, text)

format_res = map(formating, result_list)

print(max(format_res))
```

Comment: Why do you have to regular expression here?  It's quite simple. Please share what's you got.

Comment: @DanielHao I wrote this line as an example. In general, I have a text document with a lot of such substrings.

Comment: Then please show/share a more *realistic* example with the attempted code.  That way people can more quickly help you...

Comment: @DanielHao My file consists of characters a b c d e f g. I added my first version of the solution, but it seems to me that the regular expression can be simplified.

Comment: @DanielHao In my first way I do that. That is, I took the text from the file and using a regular expression found all substring like the one I wrote in the question then I used a function to check the first and last characters of the substring.